# NSPredicate to filter the Contact Number in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

```
    //  Person.h

    @interface Person : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *personImage;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* recordID;


    - (id)initWithPerson:(Person *)person;

    @end
```

I am fetching the contact from the address book and adding it into custom class Person.
 Now for every contact in address book there might be multiple number so i have used **NSMutableArray phoneNumbers** , Now i need to search the contact and get the name of the Person .

I have Tried doing like this :

```
NSPredicate *predicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phoneNumbers like %@",contactNumber];
NSArray *filtered  = [addressBookData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I am getting Nil in filtered array. Please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: What does the array contain (strings) and what is `contactNumber`? Should it be an exact match, or a partial number? At the moment you compare the full array to a string.

Comment: contact Number is String which contains Phone number that need be searched . it should be partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `like` you should be using `contains` to compare the contents of the array rather than the array itself.

Comment: Can you help me some more ? I have contact like this in address book : 8900012323 this number is without country code and number i am searching i,e 918900012323 is with country code now how should i find this ?

Comment: Try `ANY phoneNumbers CONTAINS %@`. I can't try it at the moment so you may need a slight variation on that or to use `predicateWithBlock:` and write the comparison.

Comment: I tried with ANY but its not filtering .. i also tried LIKE but its giving the Array "'Can't do regex matching on object ios"

Comment: If you can try and see later that can very helpful , phoneNumbers is mutableArray so i cannot use regx there i guess , please try and let me know

Comment: Use `predicateWithBlock:` and write the logic to compare each item in the array, then you have full control over the comparison.